# Android Why am I getting circular dependency exception

Tags: java, android, xml

Hi I can't figure out why I'm getting a circular dependency with my xml layout? I know what it is but don't know what's causing it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scroll_frame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/more_info"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/transparent_black" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start_test"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/top_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="onClickHandler"
        android:text="@string/start_test" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/top_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/start_test" />
</RelativeLayout>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/more_info"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

Can Anyone help with this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are writing `android:layout_above="@+id/top_content"` into `Button` and `android:layout_below="@+id/start_test"` into `WebView`. This is creating circular dependency for RelativeLayout.

---

Use either `android:layout_above="@+id/top_content"` or `android:layout_below="@+id/start_test"`

---

So either use

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/more_info"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/transparent_black" >

    <Button
        ....
        android:layout_above="@+id/top_content"
        .... />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/top_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Or

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/more_info"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/transparent_black" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start_test"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="onClickHandler"
        android:text="@string/start_test" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/top_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/start_test" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using

```
android:layout_above="@+id/top_content"
```

in Button and,

```
android:layout_below="@+id/start_test"
```

in WebView. Use only one.